# SWT on OS X: how to add badges to the dock icon

Tags: java, macos, swt, dock

IntelliJ IDEA, a Swing based application, for example, can show a progress indicator on the dock icon when compiling and checkmark when finishes. How can this be done for the dock icon of an SWT application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `TaskBar` and `TaskItem` classes of SWT.

It's basically:

```
display.getSystemTaskBar().getItem(shell).setProgress(66);
```

where `display` is the current display and `shell` is the window associated with the dock icon.

There's also a [code snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet336.java?view=co) for how to access the task bar.